# Python Phone Class --- printing None

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Phone:
    def __init__(self):
        self.types = ["Touch Screen","Flip", "Slider", "Bar", "Bag"]
        self.brand = "No Brand Determined"
        self.type_of_phone = "No Type of Phone has been selected"

    def get_type(self):
        return self.type_of_phone
    def change_type(self, changeTo):
        if self.check_type(changeTo):
            self.type_of_phone = changeTo
        else:
            print("The Type you wish to change the phone to is not a supported type.")

    def change_brand(self, changeTo):
        self.brand = changeTo


    def check_type(self, inQuestion):
        if inQuestion in self.types:
            return True
        return False
    def toString(self):
        return "Brand: "+self.brand+"\nType: "+self.type_of_phone+"\n"

    def menu(self):
        self.intro()
        while True:
            self.mainScreen()

    def intro(self):
        print("This program will let you create a cell phone type and brand.")

    def mainScreen(self):
        option = input(print("(1) See your phone specs \n(2) Change information\n Enter a Number: "))
        if option == "1":
            print("\n"+self.toString())
        elif option == "2":
            self.changeScreen()
        else:
            print("Enter 1 or 2. Please.")

    def changeScreen(self):
            option = input(print("\nWould you like to change the...\n(1) Type\n(2) Brand\n Enter a Number: "))
            if option == "1":
                self.changeMyType()
            elif option == "2":
                self.changeMyBrand()
            else:
                print("Enter 1 or 2")
                self.changeScreen()


    def changeMyType(self):
        optionType = input(print("\nThese are your options of phones: \n",self.types,"\nEnter an option [case sensitive]: "))
        self.change_type(optionType)

    def changeMyBrand(self):
        optionBrand = input(print("\nEnter the Brand you would like your phone to be: "))
        self.change_brand(optionBrand)



def main():

    #commands created that fully work:
    #Types of Phones to change to: Touch Screen, Flip, Slider, Bar, Bag
    #get_type()
    #change_type()

    myPhone = Phone()
    myPhone.menu()
main()
```

Run this python file. When I run it I get None printed after every print. I don't understand why. I know that when your function in python doesn't have a return it will return None, but I don't understand what is going on here. Any other feed back is great too.  Right now I have an object Phone that has a menu and other stuff. Tell me if there's another way you would approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everywhere you see `input(print("..."))`, change that to `input("...")`.  My guess is that it was getting caught up in the `print()` function, and would happily print None.

Be sure to also tag this as python3.x, as this is definitely not a 2.x question.

Answer (score 6):

it's because of the:

```
input(print("(1) See your phone specs \n(2) Change information\n Enter a Number: "))
```

The print() function returns nothing (i.e. None) that gets printed by input(), you don't need to call the print() function, therefore it should look like:

```
input("(1) See your phone specs \n(2) Change information\n Enter a Number: ")
```